# count number of values in colum that are in a certain interval, by subgroup

Tags: r, data.table

I'm doing something wrong in the following code, as the column selection does not seem to be by subgroup. Can't figure it out.

```
library(data.table)
time <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3)
mass <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5.1,4.9,5,5,5,10,10,10)
expected_check <- c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1)
dt <- data.table(time, mass, expected_check)

dt[, check:= sapply(mass, function(i) length(dt[,mass] <= (i+0.5) & dt[,mass] >= (i-0.5))), by = time]
```

I would like to check for every mass value, how many values I have in the mass column in the interval defined, at the same time. I think dt[,mass] selects the whole column and does not follow the final by = time.
Everything that I've tried suffers from the same issue.

Comment: Can you check your expected_check as it is not following the groups in 'time'

Comment: I meant the 14th and 15th observations also belong to the same group for time 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code, instead of `dt[, mass]`, which selects the whole column, we need `.SD[["mass"]]` to make sure the values within the grouping are selected

```
dt[, sapply(mass, function(i) length(.SD[["mass"]] <= (i+0.5) & 
           .SD[["mass"]] >= (i-0.5))), by = time]
```

Comment: i think it works as well without .SD i.e. `dt[, check:= sapply(mass, function(i) length(mass <= (i+0.5) & mass >= (i-0.5))), by = time]`

Answer (score 2):

Another route to produce the intended results would be to use a non-equi join:

```
time <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3)
mass <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5.1,4.9,5,5,5,10,10,10)
expected_check <- c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1)

dt <- data.table(time, mass, expected_check)

dt[dt[ , .(time, high_mass = mass + 0.5, low_mass = mass - 0.5)],
   on = .(time,
         mass <= high_mass,
         mass >= low_mass),
   check := .N,
   by = .EACHI]

dt
```

Regarding the other approach, I think you want to use `sum()` instead of `length()`. Using @chinsoon12's code:

```
dt[, wrong_check := sapply(mass, function(i) length(mass <= (i+0.5) & mass >= (i-0.5))), by = time]
dt[, correct_check := sapply(mass, function(i) sum(mass <= (i+0.5) & mass >= (i-0.5))), by = time]
dt

     time  mass expected_check check wrong_check correct_check
    <num> <num>          <num> <int>       <int>         <int>
 1:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 2:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 3:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 4:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 5:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 6:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 7:     1   2.0              7     7           7             7
 8:     2   5.0              6     6           8             6
 9:     2   5.1              6     6           8             6
10:     2   4.9              6     6           8             6
11:     2   5.0              6     6           8             6
12:     2   5.0              6     6           8             6
13:     2   5.0              6     6           8             6
14:     2  10.0              2     2           8             2
15:     2  10.0              2     2           8             2
16:     3  10.0              1     1           1             1
```

The issue is that `length()` returns the results of the vector - `c(T, F, F, F)` has the same length as `c(T, T, T, T)`. Instead, your `expected_check` is the same as the number of *TRUE* results. We can get that by using `sum()`.